# Can't build a query using CodeIgniter query builder

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, query-builder

I need to build this query :

```
SELECT p.*, c.nazwa, c.url 
FROM posty p 
INNER JOIN posty_kategorie pc
ON pc.id_posta = p.id 
INNER JOIN kategorie c 
ON c.id = pc.id_kategorii
WHERE p.url = "przykladowy-tytul-strony"
```

Using CodeIgniter's Query Builder class.

All I have for now is:

```
return $this->db->from('posty')
                ->join('posty_kategorie', 'posty_kategorie.id_posta = posty.id', 'inner')
                ->join('kategorie', 'kategorie.id = posty_kategorie.id_kategorii')
                ->where('posty.url', $url)
                ->get()->row();
```

But it this doesn't work like I want it to. It has to make this query:

```
SELECT p.*, c.nazwa, c.url 
FROM posty p 
INNER JOIN posty_kategorie pc
ON pc.id_posta = p.id 
INNER JOIN kategorie c 
ON c.id = pc.id_kategorii
WHERE p.url = "przykladowy-tytul-strony"
```

But I do not know how to put this all together : < .

Comment: Have you tried: `->result_array();` insted of `->get()->row();` ?

Comment: Query isn't finished yet. I have no Idea how to put all this things, this whole query, into CI_Query-Builder's query syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this :**

```
$this->db->select('p.*,c.nazwa,c.url');
$this->db->from('posty p');
$this->db->join('posty_kategorie pc ', 'pc.id_posta = p.id','inner');
$this->db->join('kategorie c ', 'c.id_posta = pc.id_kategorii','inner');
$this->db->where('p.url','przykladowy-tytul-strony');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```